# MVC Application Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am about to create my first proper application in ASP.NET MVC3.

It is basically a jobs site with 3 levels:

1) Users - No registration and can view all jobs posted on the website
2) Posters - Need to register and login to post adverts
3) Admin - Need to register and login to post adverts and review postings before they go live

Would you suggest I use the same Jobs controller for the three levels I mention above? With a LIST action to show jobs to "Users" and a CREATE & EDIT action for the "Posters" & "Admin"?

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable roles in your application and define 2 of them: 'Admin', 'RegisteredUser'.

You then create 3 controllers.
1 for regular users
1 for Admins
1 for RegisteredUsers.

You can then secure your controllers as follows:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you create a separate Area for Admin with all the functionalities you want for this role and for Users and Posters set different permissions for the Create/Edit actions in your Jobs Controller. You might specify something like this

```
[Authorization(Roles = UserRoles.Poster)]
    public ActionResult Create()
```